# Django: 404 when requesting static files in CSS but not in HTML

Tags: css, django

Static files are quite frustrating. Here is my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'content'),
]

# content/img/bg-mathead.jpg exists
```

Now in my HTML, calling /static/ this way works:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 order-lg-2" style="background-image: url('static/img/bg-masthead.jpg');"></div>
```

```
[27/Aug/2020 18:39:24] "GET /static/img/bg-masthead.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 693185
```

But the same call does not work in CSS:

```
/* masterhead image bakgound */
header.masthead {
  position: relative;
  /*background-color: #343a40;*/
  background: url("static/img/bg-masthead.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 8rem;
  padding-bottom: 8rem;
}
```

```
[27/Aug/2020 18:42:23] "GET /static/css/static/img/bg-masthead.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1817
```

The same thing happens with relative paths, STATIC_ROOT, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is issue has to do partly with the url pattern you are using to serve the static files. Depending on the method, the requested image url will be appended to your CSS's url like so; `/static/css/img/your_image.jpg`.

What worked for me: `staticfiles_urlpatterns` and relative paths:

```
# settings.py

from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

```
# styles.css

header.masthead {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("../img/bg-masthead.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 8rem;
  padding-bottom: 8rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css file is loaded from `/static/css/` then your background image will be loaded relatively to this path at `/static/css/static/img/bg-masthead.jpg`.

You need to change your path in your css, both solutions should work :

```css
background: url("../../static/img/bg-masthead.jpg"); // relative from /static/css/
// or
background: url("/static/img/bg-masthead.jpg"); // relative from your site url
```